# Usage example of scalaz-stream's inflate

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream

In the following usage example of `scalaz-stream` (taken from the [documentation](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream)), what do I need to change if the input and/or output is a gzipped file? In other words, how do I use [`compress`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz-stream/stable/0.6/doc/#scalaz.stream.compress$)?

```
import scalaz.stream._
import scalaz.concurrent.Task

val converter: Task[Unit] =
  io.linesR("testdata/fahrenheit.txt")
    .filter(s => !s.trim.isEmpty && !s.startsWith("//"))
    .map(line => fahrenheitToCelsius(line.toDouble).toString)
    .intersperse("\n")
    .pipe(text.utf8Encode)
    .to(io.fileChunkW("testdata/celsius.txt"))
    .run

// at the end of the universe...
val u: Unit = converter.run
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compressing the output is easy. Since `compress.deflate()` is a `Process1[ByteVector, ByteVector]` you need to plug it into your pipeline where you are emitting `ByteVector`s (that is right after `text.utf8Encode` which is a `Process1[String, ByteVector]`):

```
val converter: Task[Unit] =
  io.linesR("testdata/fahrenheit.txt")
    .filter(s => !s.trim.isEmpty && !s.startsWith("//"))
    .map(line => fahrenheitToCelsius(line.toDouble).toString)
    .intersperse("\n")
    .pipe(text.utf8Encode)
    .pipe(compress.deflate())
    .to(io.fileChunkW("testdata/celsius.zip"))
    .run
```

For `inflate` you can't use `io.linesR` to read the compressed file. You need a process that produces `ByteVector`s instead of `String`s in order to pipe them into `inflate`. (You could use `io.fileChunkR` for that.) The next step would be decoding the uncompressed data to `String`s (with `text.utf8Decode` for example) and then using `text.lines()` to emit the text line by line. Something like this should do the trick:

```
val converter: Task[Unit] =
  Process.constant(4096).toSource
    .through(io.fileChunkR("testdata/fahrenheit.zip"))
    .pipe(compress.inflate())
    .pipe(text.utf8Decode)
    .pipe(text.lines())
    .filter(s => !s.trim.isEmpty && !s.startsWith("//"))
    .map(line => fahrenheitToCelsius(line.toDouble).toString)
    .intersperse("\n")
    .pipe(text.utf8Encode)
    .to(io.fileChunkW("testdata/celsius.txt"))
    .run
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I use the above on a gzip file, I get `java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check`, and if I use `inflate(true)` instead I get `java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid block type`

Comment: A gzip file contains extra headers which `infalte` (or `java.zip.Inflater` which is used by `inflate`) does not understand, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip . `inflate` can only handle the DEFLATE-compressed payload

Comment: If you want to read from a gzip file you are better of with `io.linesR(in: => InputStream)` and Java's `GZIPInputStream`